# Trying to make a row show on dropdown selection via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(function() {
  $('#Yes_smoke').hide();
  $('#smoke').change(function() {
    if ($('#smoke').val() == 'Yes') {
      $('#Yes_smoke').show();
    } else {
      $('#Yes_smoke').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ex_smoker">
  <tr>
    <td class="prop">Are you an ex-smoker?</td>
    <td>
      <select name="smoke" id="smoke">
     <option value="" selected="selected">Choose</option>
     <option VALUE=""> </option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="smoke" id="smoke">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Choose</option>
  <option VALUE=""> </option>
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
  </tr>
</div>
<div class="ex_smoker" id="Yes_smoke">
  <tr class="Yes_smoke">
    <td class="prop" width="20%">When did you last smoke?</td>
    <td>
      <INPUT TYPE="date" NAME="medical_smoker_es_when" VALUE="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <INPUT TYPE="date" NAME="medical_smoker_es_whenb" VALUE="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

This is my jquery code as well as a part of my html form. I'm trying to make 'When did you last smoke' appear when the user selects 'Yes' from the selection above, and be hidden until then. But it is currently not working and i'm unsure why, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you have two items with the same id. That's invalid. Fix it by changing one id or move to a class

Comment: Your script should be after your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lelio pointed out, you have two identical select boxes doing the same thing. Removing the duplication seems to do the trick - see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3narpp6u/3/).

Also, make sure you are loading JQuery before your custom script i.e. ensure the line

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

or similar, referencing a local library for example, is *above* your script in your HTML page.

It is also good practice to add your scripts just before the end of your `<body>` element.

Answer (score 0):

you should write a function code inside window load -- for the purpose of  assign change event on DOM generate

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#Yes_smoke').hide();
        $('#smoke').change(function(){
            if($('#smoke').val() == 'Yes') {
                $('#Yes_smoke').show();
            } else {
                $('#Yes_smoke').hide();
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the id's.

```
<div class="ex_smoker">
 <tr>
  <td class="prop">Are you an ex-smoker?</td>
 <td>
  <select name="smoke" id="smoke">
   <option value="" selected="selected">Choose</option>
   <option VALUE=""> </option>
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
   <option value="No">No</option>
 </select>
</td>
<td>
</tr>
</div>
 <div class="ex_smoker" id="Yes_smoke">
 <tr class="Yes_smoke">
  <td class="prop" width="20%">When did you last smoke?</td>
  <td>
  <INPUT TYPE="date" NAME="medical_smoker_es_when" VALUE="">
 </td>
 <td>
  <INPUT TYPE="date" NAME="medical_smoker_es_whenb" VALUE="">
 </td>
 </tr>
</div>
```